# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' en Angular 8

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, webpack, ngfor

Tengo el siguiente problema que no puedo resolver en Angular 8, incluso con las soluciones que recomiendan en esta misma página.

Ya usé el *ngFor en otro componente así que no sé qué puede estar pasando.

En el array está todo correcto, la variable del servicio también, los módulos CommonModule y BrowserModule...la verdad que no encuentro solución.

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("  <div class="ae-masonry ae-masonry-md-2 ae-masonry-xl-4">
    <a [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let producto of _productoService.productoFiltrado" [routerLink]="['/item',producto.cod]" 
   "): ng:///AppRoutingModule/SearchComponent.html@2:7
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("  <div class="ae-masonry ae-masonry-md-2 ae-masonry-xl-4">
    [ERROR ->]<a *ngFor="let producto of _productoService.productoFiltrado" [routerLink]="['/item',producto.cod]" 
"): ng:///AppRoutingModule/SearchComponent.html@2:4
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11388)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25963)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25951)
    at compiler.js:25895
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25895)
    at compiler.js:25808
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)
```

search.component.html

```js
  <div class="ae-masonry ae-masonry-md-2 ae-masonry-xl-4">

    <a *ngFor="let producto of _productoService.productoFiltrado" [routerLink]="['/item',producto.cod]" 
    class="rk-item ae-masonry__item">
      <img src="assets/img/{{producto.url}}.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="item-meta">
        <h2>{{producto.titulo}}</h2>
        <p>{{producto.categoria}}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Si te está dando el error significa que no has incluido el módulo `Common` correctamente. Quizás lo incluiste ya pero en el lugar equivocado como por ejemplo otro módulo que no es el que contiene ese componente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que (no sé cómo) había importado un componente en "providers", si mal o recuerdo. Ya pude solucionarlo, gracias a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Deberias utilizar el  pipe | async e inicializar el objeto "productos" en tu archivo typescript

ejemplo 
Componente .TS

```
productos: Observable<any[]>;
ngOnInit(){
   this.productos= this._productoService.getProductos();
}
```

y en el HTML

`<a *ngFor="let producto of productos| async" [value]="producto.id">{{producto.nombre}}</a>`

"Recomendacion"
No usar el Async sino poner un modelo de lista
y encapsular la funcion getProductos en una funcion en si.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Se que suena raro por el nombre, pero creo que lo que te hace falta es importar en el modulo.ts el FormsModule:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...
imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule,
    ...
],
```